# ngrx router store selector in effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-router-store

Let's say I have a list and a pagination in my app. And I have this state:

```
{
  ...
  itemsPerPage: number;
  searchPhrase?: string;
}
```

Also, I have to have a `pageIndex` (current page no) and I get it from Url. For that, I have a selector:

```
export const getCurrentPageIndex = createSelector(
  selectRouteParam("pageIndex"),
  (pageIndex) => {
    return pageIndex ? parseInt(pageIndex, 10) : 1;
  }
);
```

and my route has `{:pageIndex}` parameter. So far so good.

Now, I have an effect that deals with loading data for the current page and it gets all required parameters from state (including `pageIndex` using mentioned selector) using `withLatestFrom()` and then request data from the server. So simple scenario like changing the page work.

Now, imagine having a ***Filter*** field where user can type something in and this something goes into `searchPhrase` and then I need to refresh the page BUT I need to set the current page number (`pageIndex`) to 1. And this `pageIndex` comes from router store. So, here's what I do in effects:

```
  loadPageByNumber$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(MyActions.loadPageByNumber),
        tap((action) => {
          this.router.navigate([`/someroute/${action.pageIndex}`]);
        }),
        map(() => MyActions.loadPageOfData({}))
      )
    //{ dispatch: false }
  );
```

and here's the problem. Even though I do `navigate` to new page the effect `loadPageOfData()` still sees the old `pageIndex` from the router store selector.

For example, the route `/items/30` - gets 30th page of data. Now, user types in the search phrase - the state changes and I need to reset `pageIndex` to 1 (because this is now completely different set of data). My logic doesn't work, the `pageIndex` stays the same inside the loading data effect.

How can I fix this or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A dirty fix would probably be to wrap the navigate in a setTimeout.. but ugh. The actual issue seems to be that you try to do 2 things in this single effect, and they should happen in serial. The responsibility of loading the pageData should probably happen inside the component you are routing to. 
Or another option; if you are already using the routerStore, then actions will fire once a navigation happens (check devtools). You could trigger another effect (page data thingy) on that action.

Comment: if searchPhrase changed navigation may not happen as user could be still on the 1st page.

no, I don't think the data retrieval should be put into the component. I have a facede with observable for that.

I'm scratching my head here...

Comment: ok, introduced another action and changed the chain... now it works and everything comes from router-store. But I'd really wanted to have this to work out of the box.